# How to call another method from another class in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, swift

```
mainController = (ViewController *)self.presentingViewController;   
mainController.pressureUnit = _pressureSettings.selectedSegmentIndex;
```

This is how I will do it in Objective C. How do I do this in swift?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

otherClass().methodFromOtherClass() is the syntax for swift

If you have to pass a property with an external name it might be:

otherClass().methodFromOtherClass(propertyName: stringName)  //example of passing a string

To call the method to do something, if it is returning a result of a method:

let returnValue =  otherClass().methodFromOtherClass(propertyName: stringName)

Example of accessing a property or a function

```
class CarFactory { 
   var name = ""
   var color = "" 
   var horsepower = 0 
   var automaticOption = false

   func description() { 
       println("My \(name) is \(color) and has \(horsepower) horsepowers") 
   }
} 

var myCar = CarFactory() 
myFirstCar.name = "Mustang"
myCar.color = "Red"
myCar.horsepower = 200 myCar.automaticOption = true
myFirstCar.description() // $: "My Mustang is Red and has 200 horsepowers and is Automatic"
```

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks.

Here you just call the method but not a new instance of the class.

```
class SomeClass {
    class func someTypeMethod() {
        // type method implementation goes here
    }
}

SomeClass.someTypeMethod()
```

Comment: What does the otherClass() refer to? Is it an instance of the other class? If so how do I create it? @SteveRosenberg

Comment: just gave an expanded example

Comment: Thanks very much but now I'm facing another problem. If I do something like var myCar = CarFactory() I am creating a new instance of CarFactory. What I need is to refer to the existing instance of the class. How to do this? @SteveRosenberg

Comment: You can do this two ways:  1) always refer back to myCar and you have the same instance.  This allows you t have separate instances like myCar2, etc.   If you are looking to create a singleton instance you can use something called a class function.  I will update the answer shortly.

Comment: Actually I would be glad if you could translate the above Obj C code into swift. Thank you!