# String use on another class

Tags: string, swift, class

I want to user sting in another class so if you know how to use? please help me.

I am using below link but it did't work for me. it return nil or fatal error.

> [How to call another method from another class in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26621148/how-to-call-another-method-from-another-class-in-swift)

below code:

```
var objSymbol = SymbolListVC()
 code = objSymbol.code
 selectedMarket = objSymbol.SMarket
```

below Code of Symbol class:I am gating the value in code and skt

```
var Skt: String!
var code: String!
code = sbol?["Code"] as? String
Skt = sbol?["kt"] as? String
```

Thank You.

Comment: Please show your code in your question

Comment: show your SymbolListVC class

Answer (score 0):

Does `SymbolListVC.code` have an initial value? Or do you mean to use an existing object of SymbolListVC and read the value of `code` from there?

Ideally, you should be using if directives if you are not certain that a variable will have a value

```
if let code = objSymbol.code {
    //Do your processing here
}
```

But before that, assuming you want to use an existing instance of `SymbolListVC`, your code will create a new object of the class. So you might want to change that part.

Comment: solve from this :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28315133/swift-pass-uitableviewcell-label-to-new-viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

```
var valueToPass:String!

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")

    // Get Cell Label
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow();
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as UITableViewCell!;

    valueToPass = currentCell.textLabel.text
    performSegueWithIdentifier("yourSegueIdentifer", sender: self)

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "yourSegueIdentifer") {

        // initialize new view controller and cast it as your view controller
        var viewController = segue.destinationViewController as AnotherViewController
        // your new view controller should have property that will store passed value
        viewController.passedValue = valueToPass
    }

}
```